# My program works but is very slow, it also slows down as it runs

Tags: python

I am pulling data from the Microsoft Academic Knowledge API and then using the json responses as dictionaries to extract the information I need. As I do this I add the information to a numpy array and at the end I change it to a pandas data frame to export. The program works just fine, but it takes a huge amount of time to run. It seems to slow down as it runs though, as the first few times through the loops, it only takes a few seconds, but later it takes minutes.

I have tried simplifying the if else statements as much as I can and this helped a little bit but not enough to make a big difference. I also reduced the number of times a query to the API is done as much as I can as well. Each query can only return 1000 results, but there are around 35000 results that I need.

```py
rel_info = np.array([("Title", "Author_Name", "Jornal_Published_In", "Date")])

for l in range(0, loops):                        # loops is defined above to be 35
    offset = 1000 * l
    # keep track of progress
    print("Progress:" + str(round((offset/total_res)*100, 2)) + "%")
    # get data with request to MAK. 1000 is the max count
    url = "https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=And(Composite(AA.AfN=='brigham young university'),Y>=1908)&model=latest&count=1000&offset="+str(offset)+"&attributes=Ti,D,AA.DAfN,AA.DAuN,J.JN"
    response = req.get(url + '&subscription-key={key}')

    data = response.json()

    for i in range(0, len(data["entities"])):
        new_data = data["entities"][i]
        # get new data
        new_title = new_data["Ti"]                 # get title

        if 'J' not in new_data:                    # get journal account for if keys are not in dictionaries
            new_journ = ""
        else:
            new_journ = new_data["J"]["JN"] or ""

        new_date = new_data["D"]                   # get date

        new_auth = ""                              # get authors only affiliated with BYU account for if keys are not in dictionary
        for j in range(0, len(new_data["AA"])):
            if 'DAfN' not in new_data["AA"][j]:
                new_auth = new_auth + ""
            else:
                if new_data["AA"][j]["DAfN"] == "Brigham Young University" and new_auth == "":     # posibly combine conditionals to make less complex
                    new_auth = new_data["AA"][j]["DAuN"]
                elif new_data["AA"][j]["DAfN"] == "Brigham Young University" and new_auth != "":
                    new_auth = new_auth +", "+ new_data["AA"][j]["DAuN"]
        # keep adding new data to whole dataframe
        new_info = np.array([(new_title, new_auth, new_journ, new_date)])
        rel_info = np.vstack((rel_info, new_info))
```

Comment: Please show some [MCVE] in your question

Comment: Do you know exactly where the slowdown is happening?  Perhaps the remote API is getting annoyed with you and throttling your requests?

Comment: I went back and printed some times out an watched it run and I found that the increase was coming from when I am using the vstack function from numpy. As the array gets bigger it takes longer to stack. But I still do not know how to get around this as I still need to append any new information I extract to the larger array.

Comment: Don't use an array. It makes no sense in this case, it looks like you are working with strings? Just use a normal list with . append, that will give you linear time, but using a numpy array with vstack makes this algorithm quadratic

Comment: What do you mean by "using pandas to export"? You can build a pandas dataframe from a list of lists in any case, but are you only using pandas for dumping to a csv?

Comment: I am putting it into a pandas data frame to be able to use the pandas library for some analysis later, not just to export to the csv file. I'm sorry I made it seem like that in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by changing how I was adding to the large array of data that I was collecting. Instead of adding one row of data in each iteration I built a temporary array that would hold 1000 rows of data, then I would add this temporary array to the complete data one. This took the run time down to about a minute as opposed to the 43 minutes it took before.

```
rel_info = np.array([("Title", "Author_Name", "Jornal_Published_In", "Date")])

for req_num in range(0, loops):
offset = 1000 * req_num
# keep track of progress
print("Progress:" + str(round((offset/total_res)*100, 2)) + "%")
# get data with request to MAK. 1000 is the max count
url = "https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=And(Composite(AA.AfN=='brigham young university'),Y>=1908)&model=latest&count=1000&offset="+str(offset)+"&attributes=Ti,D,AA.DAfN,AA.DAuN,J.JN"
response = req.get(url + '&subscription-key={key}')

data = response.json()

for i in range(0, len(data["entities"])):
    new_data = data["entities"][i]
    # get new data
    new_title = new_data["Ti"]                 # get title

    if 'J' not in new_data:                    # get journal account for if keys are not in dictionaries
        new_journ = ""
    else:
        new_journ = new_data["J"]["JN"] or ""

    new_date = new_data["D"]                   # get date

    new_auth = ""                              # get authors only affiliated with BYU account for if keys are not in dictionary
    for j in range(0, len(new_data["AA"])):
        if 'DAfN' not in new_data["AA"][j]:
            new_auth = new_auth + ""
        else:
            if new_data["AA"][j]["DAfN"] == "Brigham Young University" and new_auth == "":     # posibly combine conditionals to make less complex
                new_auth = new_data["AA"][j]["DAuN"]
            elif new_data["AA"][j]["DAfN"] == "Brigham Young University" and new_auth != "":
                new_auth = new_auth +", "+ new_data["AA"][j]["DAuN"]

    # here are the changes
    # keep adding to a temporary array for 1000 entities
    new_info = np.array([(new_title, new_auth, new_journ, new_date)])
    if (i == 0): work_stack = new_info
    else: work_stack = np.vstack((work_stack, new_info))
# add temporary array to whole array (this is to speed up the program)
rel_info = np.vstack((rel_info, work_stack))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the results in a pool of worker threads using `concurrent.futures` like this:

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html